# Django comments not showing up in template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-comments

I'm having trouble getting my comments to display in my template. When I test an objects comment in the shell - a list of comments are returned and they seem fine. However in my template they don't appear. It does take longer to load the page when I include {% load comments %} however nothing is shown when include {% render_comment_list for my_video %} where 'my_video' is my obj instance.

Any suggestions on how to debug this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following steps

- Make sure, that there is at least one comment for the video. You can add the following at the beginning of your views.py: `from django.contrib.comments.model import Comment` and before rendering the template: `print Comment.objects.filter(content_type = MyVideoType, object_pk = my_video.pk)`
- If you have comments, make sure that the comments are public.
- Add the following to your `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
    (r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
    ...
)
```

- Make sure, that you have `django.contrib.comments` added to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in the settings.py.

Otherwise it would be helpful if you can show the view and the template.

Comment: video doesn't seem to have the attribute comments - how do i ensure that it does?

Comment: I thought they automatically have the attribute comment. I have changed my answer regarding this.